# html input field using regex to get rid of invalid characters for filename

Tags: html, regex, escaping

I have an input field in my form where user can type in something which will be used as a foldername on a windows-system later.  Now I want to prevent ppl using any characters invalid for foldername, which are `\/:"*?<>|`. I found the `pattern`-attribute for `html input field` where I can use a regex. Now I am having trouble getting the right regex and escape this properly in my html code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="folder_name">Folder-Name:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="folder_name" name="folder_name" pattern="[^\\/:\"\*\?<>|]+" required>
    </div>                    
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to tell us what is not working and HOW it's not working.

Comment: Use `\x22` instead of `\"`: `pattern="[^\\/:\x22*?<>|]+"`

Comment: I put the code snippet in my question.

Comment: oh, that was fast^^, works fine now, thank you very much. will u put it as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `\x22` instead of a double quote:

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="folder_name">Folder-Name:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="folder_name" name="folder_name" pattern="[^\\/:\x22*?<>|]+" required>
    </div>                    
</div>
```